# Reemplazar 0 por X en Python

Tags: python

**Hola buenas tardes tengo este problema cuando intento hacer el programa para reemplazar las 0 por las x se me repite 4 veces el código, como hago para que lo imprima una sola vez?**

```
    import re

cadena = "0165031806510"
for digit in "0165031806510":
 if digit == "0":   



    cadena = cadena.replace('0','x')
    print(cadena)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca el código como texto, por favor.

Comment: Ya la edité ahora

Answer (score 2):

En resumen, tienes un

```
for digit in cadena:
    if digit == "0":
        print(cadena)
```

La condición `digit == 0` se cumple cuatro veces dentro de la cadena, por lo tanto, imprime cuatro veces la cadena.

El código hace lo que pedistes. ¿Qué esperabas que hiciera?

Comment: Ahh claro ahora entiendo, son 4 ceros que estan dentro de la cadena es por eso

Comment: Yo lo que quiero es que el la cadena con las x se imprima solo una vez

Comment: Entonces la imprimes luego de terminar el `for`. Dentro del `for` solo haces el reemplazo. Tampoco necesitas el `for`, ya que `replace` reemplaza todas las ocurrencias de una.

Comment: Como seria asi entonces?

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no necesitas hacer un `for`porque al primer `replace` ya estás cambiando todo lo `0`por la `x`, por lo tanto, las demas iteraciones nunca encontrarán otro `0` por lo que no haría falta continuar. Solo basta hacer el replace directo:

```
cadena = "0165031806510".replace('0','x')
print(cadena)
```

**MODIFICANDO TU CODIGO PARA IMPRIMIR UNA SOLA VEZ**

En todo caso a la primera que encuentres el `0` sales del `for`:

```
cadena = "0165031806510"
for digit in "0165031806510":
 if digit == "0":   
    cadena = cadena.replace('0','x')
    print(cadena)
    break
```

Esta última solo agregarías el `break` a lo que has hecho y eso hace que no repitas el `print` nuevamente.

Comment: el `for` no tiene ningún sentido, si quieres comprobar que el `0` esté en el string solo haz un `if "0" in "0165031806510": cadena = cadena.replace('0', 'x')` y listo

Comment: Mi primera respuesta hace exactamente lo que dices, sin embargo, puse al final lo que realmente pide sin altera su código.  Ahora poner un `if` previo puede ser, pero el replace directo ya lo hace implicitamente.

Comment: @Christian. El `if` es innecesario; `replace()` funciona incluso cuando no hay nada que reemplazar.

Answer (score 0):

Como han dicho otras respuestas, utilizar `.replace('0', 'x')` te hará todo el trabajo, puedes implementarlo en un método para que solo sea necesario llamarlo y este te retorne lo remplazado si en dado caso quisieras cambiar la letra en otra ocación

```
def remplazar(cadena, viejaLetra ,nuevaLetra):
    return cadena.replace(viejaLetra, nuevaLetra)

cadena = "0165031806510"
nuevaLetra = "x"
viejaLetra = "0"
print(remplazar(cadena, viejaLetra, nuevaLetra))
```

Y de esta forma no vas a tener que implementar a cada rato el replace, si no que solo llamas a tu método que sabes que te hace tu trabajo. Eventualmente este método que solo devuelve una cosa suelen ser poco usados, pero funcionan. También te dejo el de tu codigo modificado por facilidad

```
cadena = "0165031806510"
print(cadena.replace('0', 'x'))
```

Answer (score -2):

Cuando metes el print indentado al bucle for se repite el print tantas veces como se cumpla la condición, en este caso 4 por eso debes sacarlo del ciclo y lo hará una sola vez

```
import re
cadena = "0165031806510"
for digit in "0165031806510":
  if digit == "0":   
    cadena = cadena.replace('0','x') 
   
print(cadena)
```

Comment: y que se supone que es esto?

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero una respuesta que sólo tiene código se considera de baja calidad. Te invito a leer [answer] y te sugiero que edites tu respuesta para que puedas argumentar la misma. Saludos

Comment: Ten cuidado con dar respuestas de baja calidad. Esto es una advertencia, no una amenaza. [El sistema automaticamente podría bloquearte de responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)

Comment: ¿Por qué aplicas n veces el mismo `replace`? Con un sólo replace basta.